# QuickFixJ overrides Sending Time (Tag 52) value in LOGON message. How to avoid this?

Tags: authentication, tags, fix-protocol, quickfixj

Configure QuickFixJ to not override Sending Time (Tag 52) value in LOGON message. 
I am setting the Sending Time in Tag 52 in the header of the message.

***DateTime test = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);
            org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd-hh:mm:ss.SSS");
            String formatdate = fmt.print(test);
            message.getHeader().setUtcTimeStamp(SendingTime.FIELD , test.toDate());***

Once I set the value in the Tag 52, the QuickFixJ engine overrides this value with current timestamp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QuickFIXJ setting SendingTime in messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638913/quickfixj-setting-sendingtime-in-messages)

Comment: Hi. I would like to recommend you do not change any header fields. Would it work if you use an Application Date Time Field instead of using a header field?

If it does not help, you may try add/change/remove any header field using the toApp and fromApp methods. As far I know the quickfixJ engine will always fill SendingTime header field.